# Cant fill textfield on site / selenium , python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I cant fill form on this site. 
Tried everything , by id , by xpath , dont works..

```
<section class="control-group">
                        <section class="controls form-control-input-wrapper error">
                            <label for="name" class="floating-label">Your name?</label>

                            <input name="name" value="" id="name" class="form-control form-control-large" required="required" data-error-message="Requriment" data-original-title="" title="" placeholder="Your name?" type="text"><div class="tooltip error-message fade bottom in" style="top: 45px; left: 54px; display: block;"><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner">Requirment</div></div>
                        </section>
                    </section>
```

Comment: Show how you tried

Comment: You only posted the markup. Post the python/selenium that you are attempting to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following alternative xpath in your case:

```
.//*[contains(@placeholder,'Your name?')]

//input[@name='name']
```

Hope it will help you.